# Debugging patch import to/from Mercurial and Git repos: patch import is failing, but the diffs seem to match

Tags: git, mercurial, diff, patch, git-diff

I created the patch from my git repo via

```
git format-patch --relative <sha1>...<sha2>
```

to create 2 patches: `01.patch` and `02.patch`. I imported the patches to my hg repo via

```
hg import <patch file>
```

The first patch works, which is an entire file addition of `workspace/GraphUtilities/src/edu/washington/cs/utils/graph/impl/EdgeBase.java`. The second patch is a diff on the file `workspace/GraphUtilities/src/edu/washington/cs/utils/graph/impl/UndirectedEdge.java`, and I get the following output:

```
[lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/.../.Solstice_WS/7K_Manual$ hg import 0*
applying 01.patch
applying 02.patch
patching file workspace/GraphUtilities/src/edu/washington/cs/utils/graph/impl/UndirectedEdge.java
Hunk #1 FAILED at 10
Hunk #2 FAILED at 21
Hunk #3 FAILED at 30
Hunk #4 FAILED at 39
Hunk #5 FAILED at 48
Hunk #6 FAILED at 57
6 out of 6 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file workspace/GraphUtilities/src/edu/washington/cs/utils/graph/impl/UndirectedEdge.java.rej
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: patch failed to apply
[lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/.../.Solstice_WS/7K_Manual$ ls
```

Any suggestions on how to debug this? The diffs in the code (the "hunks") seem to match up perfectly. Any suggestions on where to look, or what other factors to consider when debugging?

Here is a relevant section of my .hgrc:

```
[extensions]
mq =
hgext.purge=
hgext.fetch=
shelve=

[diff]
git = 1
showfunc = 1
unified = 8
```

If interested, here are the hunks and the original `UndirectedEdge.java` file:

The hunks:

```
 .../washington/cs/utils/graph/impl/UndirectedEdge.java  | 17 +++++++++++------
 1 file changed, 11 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)

diff --git a/workspace/GraphUtilities/src/edu/washington/cs/utils/graph/impl/UndirectedEdge.java b/workspace/GraphUtilities/src/edu/washington/cs/utils/graph/impl/UndirectedEdge.java
index ef7e993..647f4f1 100644
--- a/workspace/GraphUtilities/src/edu/washington/cs/utils/graph/impl/UndirectedEdge.java
+++ b/workspace/GraphUtilities/src/edu/washington/cs/utils/graph/impl/UndirectedEdge.java
@@ -11,7 +11,8 @@ import edu.washington.cs.utils.graph.IVertex;
  * 
  * @param <V> Vertex type for the edge
  */
-public class UndirectedEdge<V extends IVertex> implements IUndirectedEdge<V>
+public class UndirectedEdge<V extends IVertex> extends EdgeBase<V> 
+   implements IUndirectedEdge<V>
 {
     /**
      * Constructs an undirected edge between <code>vertex1</code> and <code>vertex1</code>.
@@ -22,7 +23,7 @@ public class UndirectedEdge<V extends IVertex> implements IUndirectedEdge<V>
      */
     public UndirectedEdge(V vertex1, V vertex2)
     {
-        throw new RuntimeException("Method not implemented.");
+       super(vertex1, vertex2);
     }

     /**
@@ -31,7 +32,7 @@ public class UndirectedEdge<V extends IVertex> implements IUndirectedEdge<V>
     @Override
     public Set<V> getVertices()
     {
-        throw new RuntimeException("Method not implemented.");
+       return super.getVertices();
     }

     /**
@@ -40,7 +41,7 @@ public class UndirectedEdge<V extends IVertex> implements IUndirectedEdge<V>
     @Override
     public boolean equals(IUndirectedEdge<?> other)
     {
-        throw new RuntimeException("Method not implemented.");
+       return getVertices().equals(other.getVertices());
     }

     /**
@@ -49,7 +50,9 @@ public class UndirectedEdge<V extends IVertex> implements IUndirectedEdge<V>
     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object other)
     {
-        throw new RuntimeException("Method not implemented.");
+       if (other instanceof IUndirectedEdge<?>)
+           return equals((IUndirectedEdge<?>) other);
+       return false;
     }

     /**
@@ -58,6 +61,8 @@ public class UndirectedEdge<V extends IVertex> implements IUndirectedEdge<V>
     @Override
     public int hashCode()
     {
-        throw new RuntimeException("Method not implemented.");
+       int result = 17;
+       result = result * 31 + getVertices().hashCode();
+       return result;
     }
 }
-- 
1.9.1
```

UndirectedEdge.java:

```
package edu.washington.cs.utils.graph.impl;

import java.util.Set;

import edu.washington.cs.utils.graph.IUndirectedEdge;
import edu.washington.cs.utils.graph.IVertex;


/**
 * UndirectedEdge is a implementation of {@link IUndirectedEdge}.
 * 
 * @param <V> Vertex type for the edge
 */
public class UndirectedEdge<V extends IVertex> implements IUndirectedEdge<V>
{
    /**
     * Constructs an undirected edge between <code>vertex1</code> and <code>vertex1</code>.
     * 
     * @param vertex1 vertex at one end of the edge.
     * @param vertex2 vertex at the other end of the edge.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if any of the arguments is <code>null</code>
     */
    public UndirectedEdge(V vertex1, V vertex2)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Method not implemented.");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Set<V> getVertices()
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Method not implemented.");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(IUndirectedEdge<?> other)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Method not implemented.");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Method not implemented.");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Method not implemented.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an oversight on my part, but perhaps it can help others. My Mercurial repository was in DOS newline format, while my Git repository was in Unix format. The formatting difference caused the hunks to fail.

I discovered this issue when `git format-patch` outputs a `.patch` file with `\n` new lines, whereas `hg import` only took patches with `\r\n` for new lines.

This can be fixed in Vim using `:%s/\n/\r\n/g`, or [unix2dos](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_unix2dos.htm), or using Linux/Unix command-line defined [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153091/how-to-add-a-carriage-return-before-every-newline-n), and applying it to the `.patch` file.

Comment: Seems to be a Windows-specific problem that you should report on the Mercurial bug tracker. With Unix/Linux, hg definitely does not require DOS newlines.

Comment: Interesting, because I am on a Linux distro. The repositories, however, were created on a Windows machine. I think you're right - this seems like a bug. I'll report it, thanks!

Comment: Now it sounds like you have checked files into the two repositories using different end-of-line styles, and in this case, it is not a bug at all, just an incompatibility between the contents of the patch and the file to patch.

Comment: I investigated further, and yes, you are correct. My mercurial repository was in DOS format, while my Git repository was in Unix format. Thus, this entire problem is independent of the Git or Mercurial implementation. Sorry for any confusion, and thank you for the insight!

Comment: On a side note, this is quite a nasty issue for the uninitiated. It would be a great feature if `hg import` offered a debug statement when the patch fails due to a carriage return.